# Getting this Error, while integrating stripe payments. You provide API key and more

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments, python-stripe-api

I was following a YouTube video on building an Video Subscriptions Site in Django. However, while integrating stripe I got this error, "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.)."

I am beginner so I don't know much about it, here is the Models.py Code: The code is identical to the video

```
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Membership',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('membership_type', models.CharField(choices=[('Enterprise', 'ent'), ('Professional', 'pro'), ('Free', 'free')], default='Free', max_length=30)),
                ('price', models.IntegerField(default=15)),
                ('stripe_plan_id', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserMembership',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stripe_customer_id', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('membership', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='membership.membership')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Subscription',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('stripe_customer_id', models.CharField(max_length=40)),
                ('user_membership', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='membership.usermembership')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for videosub project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.

For more information on this file, see
url

For the full list of settings and their values, see
url
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See url

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-1-6st9*c$g_s%$^$t13)tf99iviiy8)pj3vvtwcw$$jr(xfx)_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #Own 
    'membership',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'videosub.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'videosub.wsgi.application'


# Database
# url

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# url

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# urls/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# url

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# url

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


if DEBUG:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''
else:
    #live Key
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''
```

There is nothing in Views.py and I was getting this error while accessing /admin/login/, when I am trying to see if models are showing in Django admin dashboard.

I appericate any help...

I was trying to interigate Stripe payments API in Django project but got this error (You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See stripe url for details, or we can help at stripe url)

Comment: You didn't share how are you using Stripe API key, I invite you to follow this python quickstart: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=python to understand how you can make API call to Stripe using python.

Comment: I see in your code you have:

if DEBUG:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''
else:
    #live Key
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''

Did you forget to fill these variables with the corresponding values?
https://stripe.com/docs/keys

Comment: Yes, brother, Is I have to put my accounts Pkey and Skey in these blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was occurred because of not filling STRIPE_API_KEYS in the settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''
else:
    #live Key
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = ''
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = ''
```

These above variables were empty, that's why this problem was caused. You can get them from your Stripe Dashboard.

Solved by the help of os4m37.